# specific select in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table  with 14 table row  and 3 column of data

i like to select the table, each row only the value of the #3 column

how do i count, i know the fisrt selector, the child... but how to not net

$('#tableofdata tr td).getmethethird

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#tableofdata tr td:nth-child(3)")
```

or simply:

```
$("#tableofdata tr td:last-child")
```

To grab the 3rd child from this, there are a number of ways:

```
$(this).find(":nth-child(3)");
```

or:

```
$(":nth-child(3)", this);
```

or simply:

```
$(this)[2]; // arrays are 0 indexed
```

Comment: i think the child(3) method is the best for me... just a question the first td is #1 or #0 ?

Comment: and how to get the child(3) from $(this)

Comment: $(this).find(":nth-child(3)") or $(":nth-child(3)", this)

Answer (score 1):

Not certain if this will be the fastest but...

```
$('#tableofdata tr td + td + td')
```

Comment: if Child(3) dont exist it will be my solution... cannot see how to get the 245 td of 367.... it will be ugly !

Answer (score 0):

what about that solution :

```
$('#mytable tr').each(function() {
    var customerId = $(this).find("td").eq(2).html();    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this solution:

```
$('#mytable tr').each(function() {
    var customerId = $(this).find("td").eq(2).html();    
});
```

Is that if your table looks like this:

```
<table id='mytable'>
  <tr>
    <td>col1</td>
    <td>col2</td>
    <td>15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>col1</td>
    <td>col2</td>
    <td>16</td>
  </tr>    
</table>
```

It would only get the ID of the first row because of the way it is constructed. So if you wanted to get all the IDs, you would do this:

```
var customers = new Array();
$('#mytable tr td:nth-child(2)').each(function() {
    customers.push($(this).html()); 
});
```

If you wanted the specific customer id of the Nth row, you would do this:

```
var customerId = $('#mytable tr').eq(N).find('td').eq(2).html();
```

Where N would be the 0-based index of the row you want.